# How do I construct a geometry point in SRID 4326 from lat and long?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point

I have a `geometry(Point,4326)` column on my table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( geom geometry(Point,4326) );
```

I want to insert into it. Currently' I am running

```
INSERT INTO foo (geom) VALUES (
  ST_GeomFromText('POINT(latitude longitude)', 4326))
);
```

To save a geometry value. I think `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(latitude longitude)', 4326)` is wrong method, I tried [from here](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/index.html)

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. The function takes X,Y parameters. Use longitude,latitude.

Comment: http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do anything for that. Just use [`ST_MakePoint`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) and cast.

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x,y),4326);
```

In an `INSERT` that looks like this,

```
-- looks like this.
INSERT INTO foo (geom) VALUES
  (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1,2),4326));
```

## Geography

The default SRID for `geography` is 4326. If you're new, I would suggest using `geography` instead of `geometry`.

```
ALTER TABLE foo drop column geom,
  ADD COLUMN geog geography(point,4326);
```

For that, just use a cast to geography or allow the implicit cast.

- Implicit cast and srid

  ```
  ST_MakePoint(x,y)
  ```
- Explicit cast, implicit srid

  ```
  ST_MakePoint(x,y)::geography
  ```
- Explicit cast and srid

  ```
  ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint(3,4), 4326 )::geography
  ```

Which looks like this,

```
INSERT INTO foo (geog) VALUES
  -- implicit cast and SRID
  ( ST_MakePoint(1,2) ),

  -- explicit cast, implicit SRID
  ( ST_MakePoint(1,2)::geography ),

   -- explicit cast and SRID
  ( ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint(3,4), 4326 )::geography );
```

Converting to text and then forcing PostgreSQL to parse the text with 
[`ST_GeomFromText`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) or [`ST_GeogFromText`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_GeogFromText.html) is silly and slow.

Answer (score 3):

This is the right method - ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || longitude || ' ' ||latitude  || ')',4326)

Comment: No, that's not.

Comment: Evan Carroll, there are different ways of creating point objects, this is the first, second - SN Tiwari confused places with latitude and longitude values, it was necessary to pay attention to this, with respect